# NSData appendBytes, adding string

Tags: objective-c, nsdata

I'm trying to create a NSData depending on a switch, but I'm having trouble adding the options to the method `appendBytes`. Adding the NSString `test` gives me an error.

Example:

```
- (void)selectCenterJustification:(int)option
{
    NSMutableData *data;
    NSString *test;
    switch (option)
    {
        case 0:
            test = @"\x0";
            break;
        case 1:
            test = @"\x1";
            break;
        case 2:
            test = @"\x2";
            break;
    }
    // does not work because of "test"
    [data appendBytes:"\x1b" "a", test length:3];

    // working
    [data appendBytes:"\x1b" "a" "\x1" length:3];
}
```

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSMutableData *data = [NSmutableData data];
NSString *test = nil;

switch (option) {
    case 0:
        test = @"\x0";
        break;
    case 1:
        test = @"\x1";
        break;
    case 2:
        test = @"\x2";
        break;
    default:
        NSLog(@"[justification]: unknown option");
        break;
}
if (test) {
    [data appendBytes:"\x1b" "a" length:2];
    [data appendBytes:[test cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] length:1];
}
```

Update

It appears you need C strings.

Comment: make sure to alloc-init data before trying to append to it

Comment: Problem isn't appending `test`, but to add it together with the other data. (see edit in original post)

Comment: What do you mean add it together with other data? If I understand correctly you should be creating an instance variable to append data too as opposed to create a local variable of NSMutableData.

Comment: Originally data is an instance variable. I just changed it to local so the example will work after copying it :).

Comment: Okay updated my answer to use NSMutableString which you can append to then convert to NSData. Hope I understood correctly.

Comment: I tried using mutablestring before and it gives me the wrong result. when checking data, it gives me the hex code `<1b40d0ae 35>` while it should be `<1b401b61 02> `. I need to use appendBytes though, need to send it to the printer.

Comment: I think you need to be using c strings, that would explain why it was not working in your example. Updated my answer again :-)

Comment: awesome, it's working now. Strange though. I tried this option before and it wasnt working... ;p thanks! (changed to NSASCIIStringEncoding btw)